# comparison ex of list comprehension and lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

```
Celsius = [66.5,45.2,33.5,55.5]
Fahrenheit = [((float(9)/5)*x + 32) for x in Celsius]
```

How would I write this in a lambda function? Ex: lambda x,y:x+y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Fahrenheit = list(map(lambda x: x * 9.0 / 5 + 32, Celsius))
```

In general, list comprehension (what your example does) can be converted to a combination of `map` and a `lambda` (or other function).

**EDIT**

You could also use `lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32`; I was just trying to simplify the expression. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
TempCtoF = lambda c: 9/5 * c + 32
TempFtoC = lambda f: 5/9 * (f - 32)

Celsius = [66.5,45.2,33.5,55.5]
Fahrenheit = [TempCtoF(c) for c in Celsius]
```

or

```
Fahrenheit = list(map(TempCtoF, Celsius))
```